# Dropdown links using jQuery .slidetoggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using the following code to create a dropdown menu using .slidetoggle and jQuery:

```
<ul>
    <li class="expand"><span>Dropdown</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine and clicking li.expand reveals/hides the child li's.

The problem is that when a link is clicked (e.g. google.com), on most browsers the menu first toggles ul.sub-menu up before activating the link.

How do I stop the menu from toggling up when a link is clicked?

For clarification the above code works as required on Safari.

JSFiddle example if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/fcs5n8o6/3/

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
$('.sub-menu').find('a').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();                          
});
```

According to [event.stopPropagation method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) clicked links will not notify li elements about clicks (they do it now), and click handler for li will not fire.

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79s0yrdn/)

There is even better and concise solution:

```
<ul>
    <li class="expand"><span>Dropdown</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(".expand").click(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
        $('.sub-menu').find('li').click(function(event){
             event.stopPropagation();                          
        });
    });
</script>
```

[new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3epff0w4/)

I also edited jQuery selectors, they were a little bit too exuberant and not very effective.

As for your site:
 find file custom.js?ver=1 line 405:

```
$(".leftnav ul li.removelink.driver").click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".leftnav ul li.removelink.driver li").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

change for this:

```
$(".leftnav ul li.removelink.driver").click(function() {

        $(".leftnav ul li.removelink.driver li").slideToggle("slow")
        .click(function(event){event.stopPropagation();});

    });
```

Comment: I agree with you, sir.

Comment: I've tried both variants of this as suggested by yourself and @zer00ne but neither has worked. Here is a link to the staging environment (sidebar on the left) to clarify the issue: http://bit.ly/1LkpJNp

Comment: I just opened fiddle on Safari, everything works as expected... Did you try updated fiddle? Does it show unwanted behavior?

Comment: Added solution for bit.ly/1LkpJNp, please, try it.

Comment: @Lunokhod thanks for that. I've updated the code in custom.js as suggested but still have the same issue. To clarify this does not effect Safari. Only Chrome and IE. See video: https://youtu.be/PALLROFT70s. The first browser is Chrome, the second is Safari.

Comment: Oh, it is so entangled, I can't find class 'driver' now. You could just add $('.sub-menu').find('a').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();                          
}); near that click handlers. I just run it in console and things were done! (if you want to run it in console change $ to jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `event.stopPropagation();`

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/yoggar2z/1/